# Converting Plain Text URL to Clickable Link

Tags: javascript, html

I have an app that I am making and would like to see a functionality similar to Microsoft Word, where if you start with `http://` or `www.` and finish the URL with a `.tld`, and hit space or enter, Word'll will covert the text to a clickable link. I want the same to happen when a link is posted.

Here's a GIF of what I am looking for:

http://i.makeagif.com/media/5-18-2016/lefWPr.gif (I don't have 10 rep. points)

I prefer JS or any non server side script.

Comment: Check this project out - https://github.com/bryanwoods/autolink-js

Comment: Do have a starting snippet of code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pattern = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/g;

var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var text = document.querySelector('#text').value;
  var output = document.querySelector('#output');

  if (pattern.test(text)) {
    output.innerHTML += '<a href="' + text.match(pattern) + '">' + text.match(pattern) + '</a><br>';
  } else {
    output.innerHTML += text+"<br>";
  }
});
```

```css
p, textarea,button{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" cols="30" rows="10">

</textarea>

<button id="button" type="button">submit</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```